# How to copy file to a directory which has partial fixed name and other half changes with integer values. using ant script

Tags: ant

I want to use ant script to copy a file to directory which is not path is fixed  but last folder name is not fixed. 
Path D:\Home\Config\plugins\1780.
The last folder name (1780) it changes randomly and is not fixed.
I want to copy a war file in to that folder.
How can I do it.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: What does randomly means? Is there a standard format that folder name has? What could be the possible values for this folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate (once) over *plugins* subdirectories and copy to the (only?) entry.

```
<target name="run">
   <foreach target="loop" param="loop.param">
      <dirset dir="D:\Home\Config\plugins" />
   </foreach>
</target>
<target name="loop">
   <copy todir="$loop.param">
   ...
   </copy>
</target>
```